# Convert pressure cooker recipes for 8 psi

Tags: pressure-cooker

I have a new electric multi cooker, it works at 8PSI and I am having difficulty at finding out how to convert stove top pressure cooker times at 15PSI down to 8PSI, hoping for your help.
Regards
Joan